# Implementing normalization/rescalement from a Tutorial

Tags: code-review

I'm trying to implement a rescale/normalization as is described in [here](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~frey/QuantitativeFinance/Resources/TutorialsWorkshops/Tutorial_HMM/HMMUG_20091222_05.pdf) by mathematical expressions in page 10, and code in the top part of page 16. The notebook is also available [here](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~frey/QuantitativeFinance/Resources/TutorialsWorkshops/Tutorial_HMM/HMMUG_20091222_05.nb). The objective of the normalization is for the elements, created in a recursive way, of a vector to never go below machine-size, and to be able to still be able to use the normalized values to compute some variables of interest.

Here is my adapted (non)working example:

```
n = 999;
alpha = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, n}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
    (*the totals below are just for another rescalement. 
They don't seem to be the problem, since even without them the program gets the same error.*)
    bmat = (#/Total[#] &) /@ 
       RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, n}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
    miota = ((#/Total[#] &) /@ 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20])[[1]];
mtransprob = (#/Total[#] &) /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

listalpha = Range[n];
cf = Compile[{{y, _Real}},

   alpha[[1, 1]] = miota[[1]]*bmat[[1, 1]];
   alpha[[2, 1]] = miota[[2]]*bmat[[2, 1]];

   aux = Transpose[mtransprob];
   ct = 1;

   While[ct <= n - 1,

    alpha[[1 ;; 2, ct + 1]] = (aux.alpha[[1 ;; 2, ct]])*
      bmat[[1 ;; 2, ct + 1]];

    listalpha[[ct + 1]] = 1/(Total[alpha[[1 ;; 2, ct + 1]]]);
    (*The rescalement is done here. 
It's just an average, that should make the elements of the vector alpha with value between ]0,1[ 
and prevent the values of the alpha recursion from going below machine-size. However it doesn't seem to work*)
    alpha[[1 ;; 2, ct + 1]] = 
     alpha[[1 ;; 2, ct + 1]]*listalpha[[ct + 1]];

    ct = ct + 1;

    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

So, if I run `cf[1]`, which will call the function cf and update the matrix alpha, I get the error:

```
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0.*10^-3 encountered. "
```

I get the same error, even if I remove the compile command. I think it has to do with the way the initial variables are initiated. But I don't understand why, since I'm applying the same reasoning as this tutorial...

Edit1: It seems if at some steps of the while I put //N the error doesn't show up anymore...